# Visual Studio 2022 New Project Exception

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

We have created our own Visual Studio Template extension.
We have this working for many years, but in our upgrade to .NET 6 we have to make a few changes.

When trying to create a new project from our template, we get this exception:
[image]

The error itself is not much helpfull. I tried to find ways to get more logging out of VS, the only option i found is the run DevEnv.exe with -Log. Which i did, it gave me more meaningless details about the error, still nothing i could work with.

```
  <entry>
    <record>2531</record>
    <time>2023/11/24 06:08:07.091</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Template provider aggregator</source>
    <description>System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonIDE.Solutions.Interop.IVsNativeEnvironmentInternal.WizLoadAndRunFile(String pwszWizard, String pwszDestination, Boolean bCloseSolution, Boolean bRunSilent, Array psaCustomParams, String pwszFrameworkVersion)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonIDE.Solutions.Dte.DteSolution.&lt;AddFromTemplateExAsync&gt;d__256.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonIDE.Solutions.Dte.DteSolution.&lt;AddFromTemplateExAsync&gt;d__256.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask.CompleteOnCurrentThread()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading.JoinableTask`1.CompleteOnCurrentThread()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonIDE.Solutions.Dte.DteSolution.AddFromTemplateEx(String FileName, String Destination, String ProjectName, String SolutionName, Boolean Exclusive, UInt32 Options)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CommonIDE.Solutions.Dte.DteSolution.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass25_0.&lt;EnvDTE100.Solution4.AddFromTemplateEx&gt;b__0()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.NewProjectDialog.LegacyVsTemplateProvider.GetInstantiationResult(CreateProjectResult result)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.NewProjectDialog.LegacyProjectTemplateProvider.&lt;InstantiateTemplateAsync&gt;d__7.MoveNext()&#x000D;&#x000A;--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TemplateProviders.TemplateProviderSupport.ExceptionLoggingTemplateProviderDecorator.&lt;InstantiateTemplateAsync&gt;d__9.MoveNext()</description>
  </entry>
```

In older versions of Visual Studio, you could use a 2nd instance and attach it to the other instance. This does not work anymore, i cannot get any information out of my attached process.

What other options do i have to figure out which file Visual Studio appears to be missing?

Answer (score 1):

Try to attach the Visual Studio debugger to another instance and replicate the error. This way you may be able to get more insight as to what is wrong.

> In older versions of Visual Studio, you could use a 2nd instance and attach it to the other instance. This does not work anymore, i cannot get any information out of my attached process.

It does work. I faced a similar issue recently and did just that. Be sure to have the "Just My Code" checkbox **disabled** in Debug -> Options. Otherwise the debugger will not report the exception.